# advantage and disadvantage of smarty template

Tags: php, templates, smarty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I use templating system in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436014/why-should-i-use-templating-system-in-php)

I'm new to Smarty.

Why are people showing interest in this framework? What are the advantages of it? Also, a lot of people avoid templates, what is the reason?

What is the real reason people choose the Smarty templating system?

How much really smarty best for web development?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the best way to use a template engine is using of regular HTML in .php files as a templates.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked and discussed before in many shades, this is a link list to the most popular ones:

- [Why should I use templating system in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436014/why-should-i-use-templating-system-in-php)
- [Smarty, the best choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630714/smarty-the-best-choice)
- [What’s the best way to separate PHP Code and HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-php-code-and-html)
- [Smarty benchmark, anyone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364989/smarty-benchmark-anyone)